How to programmatically (in Java, not XML) configure JDBC connection pool in Tomcat?
here is a simple app that starts Tomcat from code:
public class TestStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8080);
        tomcat.getConnector();

        String contextPath = "";
        String docBase = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();

        Context context = tomcat.addContext(contextPath, docBase);

        String servletName = "HelloServlet";
        tomcat.addServlet(contextPath, servletName, new HelloServlet());
        context.addServletMappingDecoded("/test", servletName);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}

Let's say I want to use a JDBC connection in the servlets and get a connection from the  JDBC pool. How to do this?

For those interested, here is how I did this in JavaLite:
https://github.com/javalite/javalite/blob/master/embedded-tomcat/src/main/java/org/javalite/tomcat/EmbeddedTomcat.java
